# OpenSL ES on android Playback rate

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, opensl, mediaplayback

I am currently developing an app that requires the tempo of music to be slowed down, I searched online and the only real option to do this in android is OpenSL ES. I am starting with the basics so i just got an audio file playing but for some reason i cant change the tempo. I get the following error

```
04-04 15:32:51.950: W/libOpenSLES(12848): Leaving Object::GetInterface (SL_RESULT_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED)
```

I have checked to see if the feature is supported and the documentation says it is so maybe i have some mistakes in my code? I have never used C++ before now so any help is appreciated. My code is as follows

```
* Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 */

/* This is a JNI example where we use native methods to play sounds
 * using OpenSL ES. See the corresponding Java source file located at:
 *
 *   src/com/example/nativeaudio/NativeAudio/NativeAudio.java
 */

#include <assert.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>

// for __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "YourApp", "formatted message");
// #include <android/log.h>

// for native audio
#include <SLES/OpenSLES.h>
#include <SLES/OpenSLES_Android.h>

// for native asset manager
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
#include <android/asset_manager_jni.h>

// pre-recorded sound clips, both are 8 kHz mono 16-bit signed little endian

static const char hello[] =
#include "hello_clip.h"
;

static const char android[] =
#include "android_clip.h"
;

// engine interfaces
static SLObjectItf engineObject = NULL;
static SLEngineItf engineEngine;

// output mix interfaces
static SLObjectItf outputMixObject = NULL;
static SLEnvironmentalReverbItf outputMixEnvironmentalReverb = NULL;


// aux effect on the output mix, used by the buffer queue player
static const SLEnvironmentalReverbSettings reverbSettings =
    SL_I3DL2_ENVIRONMENT_PRESET_STONECORRIDOR;

// file descriptor player interfaces
static SLObjectItf fdPlayerObject = NULL;
static SLPlayItf fdPlayerPlay;
static SLSeekItf fdPlayerSeek;
static SLMuteSoloItf fdPlayerMuteSolo;
static SLVolumeItf fdPlayerVolume;


// synthesized sawtooth clip
#define SAWTOOTH_FRAMES 8000
static short sawtoothBuffer[SAWTOOTH_FRAMES];

// pointer and size of the next player buffer to enqueue, and number of remaining buffers
static short *nextBuffer;
static unsigned nextSize;
static int nextCount;

// playback rate (default 1x:1000)
static SLpermille playbackMinRate = 500;
static SLpermille playbackMaxRate = 2000;
static SLpermille playbackRateStepSize;
static SLPlaybackRateItf fdPlaybackRate;


// create the engine and output mix objects
void Java_com_example_nativeaudio_NativeAudio_createEngine(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz)
{
    SLresult result;

    // create engine
    result = slCreateEngine(&engineObject, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
    (void)result;

    // realize the engine
    result = (*engineObject)->Realize(engineObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
    assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
    (void)result;

    // get the engine interface, which is needed in order to create other objects
    result = (*engineObject)->GetInterface(engineObject, SL_IID_ENGINE, &engineEngine);
    assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
    (void)result;

    // create output mix, with environmental reverb specified as a non-required interface
    const SLInterfaceID ids[1] = {SL_IID_ENVIRONMENTALREVERB};
    const SLboolean req[1] = {SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE};
    result = (*engineEngine)->CreateOutputMix(engineEngine, &outputMixObject, 1, ids, req);
    assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
    (void)result;



    // realize the output mix
    result = (*outputMixObject)->Realize(outputMixObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
    assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
    (void)result;

    // get the environmental reverb interface
    // this could fail if the environmental reverb effect is not available,
    // either because the feature is not present, excessive CPU load, or
    // the required MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permission was not requested and granted
    result = (*outputMixObject)->GetInterface(outputMixObject, SL_IID_ENVIRONMENTALREVERB,
            &outputMixEnvironmentalReverb);
    if (SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result) {
        result = (*outputMixEnvironmentalReverb)->SetEnvironmentalReverbProperties(
                outputMixEnvironmentalReverb, &reverbSettings);
        (void)result;
    }
    // ignore unsuccessful result codes for environmental reverb, as it is optional for this example

}


// expose the mute/solo APIs to Java for one of the 3 players


// expose the volume APIs to Java for one of the 3 players

// enable reverb on the buffer queue player
jboolean Java_com_example_nativeaudio_NativeAudio_enableReverb(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz,
        jboolean enabled)
{
    SLresult result;

    // we might not have been able to add environmental reverb to the output mix
    if (NULL == outputMixEnvironmentalReverb) {
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    return JNI_TRUE;
}

// create asset audio player
jboolean Java_com_example_nativeaudio_NativeAudio_createAssetAudioPlayer(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz,
        jobject assetManager, jstring filename)
{
    SLresult result;

    // convert Java string to UTF-8
    const char *utf8 = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, filename, NULL);
    assert(NULL != utf8);

    // use asset manager to open asset by filename
    AAssetManager* mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager);
    assert(NULL != mgr);
    AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, utf8, AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);

    // release the Java string and UTF-8
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, filename, utf8);

    // the asset might not be found
    if (NULL == asset) {
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    // open asset as file descriptor
    off_t start, length;
    int fd = AAsset_openFileDescriptor(asset, &start, &length);
    assert(0 <= fd);
    AAsset_close(asset);

    // configure audio source
    SLDataLocator_AndroidFD loc_fd = {SL_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDFD, fd, start, length};
    SLDataFormat_MIME format_mime = {SL_DATAFORMAT_MIME, NULL, SL_CONTAINERTYPE_UNSPECIFIED};
    SLDataSource audioSrc = {&loc_fd, &format_mime};

    // configure audio sink
    SLDataLocator_OutputMix loc_outmix = {SL_DATALOCATOR_OUTPUTMIX, outputMixObject};
    SLDataSink audioSnk = {&loc_outmix, NULL};

    // create audio player
    const SLInterfaceID ids[3] = {SL_IID_SEEK, SL_IID_MUTESOLO, SL_IID_VOLUME};
    const SLboolean req[3] = {SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE};
    result = (*engineEngine)->CreateAudioPlayer(engineEngine, &fdPlayerObject, &audioSrc, &audioSnk,
            3, ids, req);
    assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
    (void)result;

    // realize the player
    result = (*fdPlayerObject)->Realize(fdPlayerObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
    assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
    (void)result;

    // get the play interface
    result = (*fdPlayerObject)->GetInterface(fdPlayerObject, SL_IID_PLAY, &fdPlayerPlay);
    assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
    (void)result;

    // get the seek interface
    result = (*fdPlayerObject)->GetInterface(fdPlayerObject, SL_IID_SEEK, &fdPlayerSeek);
    assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
    (void)result;

    // get the mute/solo interface
    result = (*fdPlayerObject)->GetInterface(fdPlayerObject, SL_IID_MUTESOLO, &fdPlayerMuteSolo);
    assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
    (void)result;

    // get the volume interface
    result = (*fdPlayerObject)->GetInterface(fdPlayerObject, SL_IID_VOLUME, &fdPlayerVolume);
    assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
    (void)result;

    // enable whole file looping
    result = (*fdPlayerSeek)->SetLoop(fdPlayerSeek, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, 0, SL_TIME_UNKNOWN);
    assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
    (void)result;

    // get playback rate interface
       result = (*fdPlayerObject)->GetInterface(fdPlayerObject,
                SL_IID_PLAYBACKRATE, &fdPlaybackRate);
        assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);

        SLuint32 capa;
        result = (*fdPlaybackRate)->GetRateRange(fdPlaybackRate, 0,
                    &playbackMinRate, &playbackMaxRate, &playbackRateStepSize, &capa);
        assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);

        result = (*fdPlaybackRate)->SetPropertyConstraints(fdPlaybackRate,
                            SL_RATEPROP_PITCHCORAUDIO);

        if (SL_RESULT_PARAMETER_INVALID == result) {
    //        LOGD("Parameter Invalid");
        }
        if (SL_RESULT_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED == result) {
    //        LOGD("Feature Unsupported");
        }
        if (SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result) {
            assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
       //     LOGD("Success");
        }

 //     result = (*fdPlaybackRate)->SetRate(fdPlaybackRate, playbackMaxRate);
   //        assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);

            SLpermille SLrate;
            result = (*fdPlaybackRate)->GetRate(fdPlaybackRate, &SLrate);
            assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);

            // enable whole file looping
            result = (*fdPlayerSeek)->SetLoop(fdPlayerSeek, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE, 0, SL_TIME_UNKNOWN);
            assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
            (void)result;

    return JNI_TRUE;
}

/*JNIEXPORT void Java_com_example_stackoverflowcode_NativeAudio_setRate(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jint rate) {

    result = (*fdPlayerRate)->SetRate(fdPlayerRate, playbackMaxRate);
               assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);

}
*/
JNIEXPORT void Java_com_example_stackoverflowcode_NativeAudio_setRate(
        JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jint rate) {
    if (NULL != fdPlaybackRate) {
        SLresult result;

        result = (*fdPlaybackRate)->SetRate(fdPlaybackRate, rate);
            assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);

    }
}


// set the playing state for the asset audio player
void Java_com_example_nativeaudio_NativeAudio_setPlayingAssetAudioPlayer(JNIEnv* env,
        jclass clazz, jboolean isPlaying)
{
    SLresult result;

    // make sure the asset audio player was created
    if (NULL != fdPlayerPlay) {

        // set the player's state
        result = (*fdPlayerPlay)->SetPlayState(fdPlayerPlay, isPlaying ?
            SL_PLAYSTATE_PLAYING : SL_PLAYSTATE_PAUSED);
        assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
        (void)result;
    }

}


// shut down the native audio system
void Java_com_example_nativeaudio_NativeAudio_shutdown(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz)
{

    // destroy file descriptor audio player object, and invalidate all associated interfaces
    if (fdPlayerObject != NULL) {
        (*fdPlayerObject)->Destroy(fdPlayerObject);
        fdPlayerObject = NULL;
        fdPlayerPlay = NULL;
        fdPlayerSeek = NULL;
        fdPlayerMuteSolo = NULL;
        fdPlayerVolume = NULL;
    }

    // destroy output mix object, and invalidate all associated interfaces
    if (outputMixObject != NULL) {
        (*outputMixObject)->Destroy(outputMixObject);
        outputMixObject = NULL;
        outputMixEnvironmentalReverb = NULL;
    }

    // destroy engine object, and invalidate all associated interfaces
    if (engineObject != NULL) {
        (*engineObject)->Destroy(engineObject);
        engineObject = NULL;
        engineEngine = NULL;
    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think here you some more steps:

1) get the DynamicInterfaceManagementItf
2) add PlayBackRateItf thorough DynamicInterfaceManagementItf
3) get the interface on your object

```
// get dynamic interface
result = (*fdPlayerObject)->GetInterface(fdPlayerObject,
        SL_IID_DYNAMICINTERFACEMANAGEMENT,
        (void*) &dynamicInterfaceManagementItf);
CheckErr(result);

// add playback rate itf
result = (*dynamicInterfaceManagementItf)->AddInterface(
        dynamicInterfaceManagementItf, SL_IID_PLAYBACKRATE,
        SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
CheckErr(result);

// get the playbackrate interface
result = (*fdPlayerObject)->GetInterface(fdPlayerObject,
        SL_IID_PLAYBACKRATE, &fdPlaybackRateItf);
CheckErr(result);
```

Hope it helps you